# iptables configuration for Transparent squid proxy

Tags: linux, iptables, squid, sles

I have to setup a transparent squid proxy server using `iptables` and `squid`. Following is the scenario:

`[INTERNAL NETWORK] -> [Main Switch] -> [Proxy Server] -> [Firewall] -> [EXTERNAL NETWORK]`

I am having a system with SLES 11 SP3 installed on it and I am supposed to configure it as a router/gateway first, before making any `squid` configurations.

What should be the `iptables` rules to meet the requirements?

Comment: I think you need to this concept : http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/TransparentProxy-6.html , The given link doesn't explain squid configuration , when you need to transparency proxy , you need to configure squid along with iptables or PF, ipfw , or any firewall.

Comment: By the way, I don't recall to say SELS itself has a firewall buitl-in beside iptables. YAST configure it. be carefule.

Comment: @MohsenPahlevanzadeh - You're right. It does have a built-in firewall. I was not able to connect it through ssh, until I disabled it.

Answer (score 1):

To redirect traffic that doesn't know about the proxy (i.e. it's not configured in the browser) so that it is sent to squid, you need to add a PREROUTING rule with iptables:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i internal_interface -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3128
```

Replace `internal_interface` with whatever interface the client traffic will come from, e.g. `eth0`.

This will redirect traffic from your internal network bound for port 80 to port 3128 on the local system (that is the default port for squid, adjust accordingly).

As you only asked for the iptables config I'll not go into the necessary squid config.

Comment: To proxy traffic from localhost on the server you need additionally something like  `iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -o external_interface --dport 80 -m owner ! --uid-owner proxy -j  REDIRECT --to-ports 3128` where `proxy` is the username of squid.

Comment: The answer is for the case, the server is already working as a (normal) gateway with `echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` and corresponding iptables rules.